# plotting with matplotlib in jupyter: effect of separating code across cells

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am learning pandas and matplotlib and I see this strange behaviour that I can not understand.

the code is the following:

```
# plot the histograms for each feature
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
for i, feature in enumerate(df.columns):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    df[feature].plot(kind='hist', title=feature)
    plt.xlabel(feature)
```

now the result is as follows:

[image]

All fine.

Now if I separate the code into two cells the result changes:

[image]

Why is the result different?

Comment: Can you post version of jupyter, pandas and matplotlib. You can find it by issuing python -p pip freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.figure()` creates a new `Figure` instance, `plt.subplot` will add a subplot to the current figure - and create an instance if none currently exists.

In the first case, `plt.figure()` creates a `Figure` instance with a size of `(15,5)` and that instance is now the 'current figure' until it goes out of scope, it is closed, or a new `Figure` is instantiated (or the 'current figure' is changed by some other means). `plt.subplot` will then add a subplot to this `Figure` instance - the result is a figure of size `(15,5)` with 4 subplots as desired.

In the second case, when the call to `plt.figure()` is in a different cell it will no longer be the 'current figure' in a different cell. This is because **the figure is closed at the end of the execution of the first cell** - that's why you see the `<Figure size 1080x360 with 0 Axes>` output.

The way around this is to store the returned `Figure` instance from `plt.figure()` and then use `Figure.add_subplot` instead of `plt.subplot`. The first cell would then be

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
```

and the second would be

```py
for i, feature in enumerate(df.columns):
    fig.add_subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    df[feature].plot(kind='hist', title=feature)
    plt.xlabel(feature)
```